# Template member function in a template class not found when called on an instance

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

```
namespace {
enum class API { CPU, CUDA };

template <API Api>
class Allocator {
    void* malloc(int size) const;
    void free(void* ptr) const;

    template <typename T>
    T* alloc1(int num) const {
        return static_cast<T*>(malloc(num * static_cast<int>(sizeof(T))));
    }
};

template <typename T, API Api>
T* alloc2(const Allocator<Api> allocator, int num) {
    return static_cast<T*>(allocator.malloc(num * static_cast<int>(sizeof(T))));
}

template <>
class Allocator<API::CPU> {
public:
    void* malloc(int size) const { return nullptr; }

    void free(void* ptr) const {}
};

Allocator<API::CPU> allocator;
int* ptr1 = allocator.template alloc1<int>(1);

int* ptr2 = alloc2<int>(allocator, 1);

}
```

`alloc1` call doesn't compile with error

```
.../src/test.cc:29:32: error: no member named 'alloc1' in '(anonymous namespace)::Allocator<API::CPU>'
int* ptr1 = allocator.template alloc1<int>(1);
                               ^
.../src/test.cc:29:38: error: expected unqualified-id
int* ptr1 = allocator.template alloc1<int>(1);
                                     ^
.../src/test.cc:29:42: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
int* ptr1 = allocator.template alloc1<int>(1);
                                      ~~~^
```

Removing `template` doesn't help:

```
.../src/test.cc:29:33: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
int* ptr1 = allocator.alloc1<int>(1);
                             ~~~^
.../src/test.cc:29:23: error: no member named 'alloc1' in '(anonymous namespace)::Allocator<API::CPU>'; did you mean 'malloc'?
int* ptr1 = allocator.alloc1<int>(1);
                      ^~~~~~
                      malloc
```

I am using Clang 9 with C++14 standard.

`alloc2` works as a workaround, so I just want to know why `alloc1` doesn't or what is the proper way to declare/call it.

EDIT: it turns out that providing specializations of `Allocator<API::CPU>::malloc`/`free` instead of a specialization of `Allocator<API::CPU>` gives the behavior I expected, but probably inheritance will be more appropriate in my original situation.

Comment: Your specialization does not define `alloc1()`, that's all. Which part of this is unclear to you? Do you see `alloc1()` defined in your specialization of `Allocator<API::CPU>`? I don't see it. You don't see it. Neither does your compiler.

Comment: specialization and inheritance are two very different things. If you want to have different specializations inherit from a common base then you need to do that

Comment: I suspect you're expecting the implementation in the base template to be used as a default implementation, similarly to Haskell's type classes, but that's not how templates work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`class Allocator<API::CPU>` specialisation simply does not define the member function; It is only defined in the generic template. If you want to avoid repeating same definition for multiple specilisations, you can use inheritance. Like this for example:

```
struct BaseAllocator {
    template <typename T>
    T* alloc1(int num) const {
        ...
    }
};

template <API Api>
class Allocator : public BaseAllocator {
    ...
};

template <>
class Allocator<API::CPU> : public BaseAllocator {
    ...
};
```

P.S. Your `alloc1` is private, so you wouldn't have access to it from outside the class anyway.

Comment: I managed to lose `public` while reducing the problem somehow, oh well.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yeah, easy to miss when the problem is inability to call the function at all :) I prefer to use `struct` for minimal examples unless the problem relates to access specifiers directly.

Answer (score 2):

In this specialization of the class

```
template <>
class Allocator<API::CPU> {
public:
    void* malloc(int size) const { return nullptr; }

    void free(void* ptr) const {}
};
```

there is no member function alloc1.

And in these statements

```
Allocator<API::CPU> allocator;
int* ptr1 = allocator.template alloc1<int>(1);
```

there is used this specialization of the class template.